# How to use 2 tiling background images using the HTML tag and the BODY tag

Tags: html, css

I have a tiling background image, but I want to overlay another tiling image over it. I have tried using:

```
html {background: transparent url('../images/bgtile.jpg') repeat top center;}
body {background: transparent url('../images/body.png') repeat-y top center;}
```

But it doesn't work quite right. The body tag behaves like a div because it doesn't stretch to fit the screen.

I am sure that I am just missing something obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (It works in FF3 and IE7 and I assume Safari and Chrome):

```
html {
     background: transparent url('../images/bgtile.jpg') repeat top center;
     height: 100%;
}
body {
     background: transparent url('../images/body.png') repeat-y top center;
     height: 100%;
     overflow-y: scroll;
}
html > body {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: wow, that was fast. Thanks for the quick response, that works really well.

Comment: no problem, this bugged me for a week and now I have it just sitting in a text file waiting to be used, I just had to change the filenames to match.

Answer (score 0):

Why not work with a 100% width / height  within the ? That should work with every browser.

Comment: it doesn't work very well once you scroll and some other things that I forget at the moment.